# What subsets $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are such that $\partial(A)=\partial(\partial(A))$?

Tags: general-topology

What subsets $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are such that $\partial(A)=\partial(\partial(A))$?

Is it necessary for a set to have an empty boundary for this property to hold?

Comment: That is certainly not necessary, for $\partial \partial \partial A=\partial \partial A$ and $\partial A$ need not be empty.

Comment: The question should be readable on its own; it should not be a continuation of the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A guess at what's going through your head:

It is important to distinguish from the topological notion of a border of a subset of some ambient topology from a somewhat more intuitive (and in some settings more useful) sense of a border that you might have in mind.

For example, consider a line segment $L \subset \Bbb R^2$ under the usual topology. The intuitive result might be that $\partial L$ should consist of the endpoints of the line segment.  However, with a careful application of the definition, you should find that $\partial L = L$.

Now, a hint towards classification: remember that $\partial B = \bar B \setminus \mathrm{int}(B)$.  What can we say if $B = \bar B$ (i.e. if $B$ is closed)? If $B = \partial A$, must it be closed?

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary that the boundary have empty interior. It's also sufficient actually.

I assume the definition $\partial A =\overline{A}-A^\circ$.

Then we have

$$\partial\partial A=\overline{\left(\overline{A}-A^\circ\right)}-\left(\overline{A}-A^\circ\right)^\circ=\left(\overline{A}-A^\circ\right)-\left(\overline{A}-A^\circ\right)^\circ$$

Since $\left(\overline{A}-A^\circ\right)^\circ$ is a subset of $\left(\overline{A}-A^\circ\right)$, if we have $\partial A=\partial\partial A$ then $\left(\overline{A}-A^\circ\right)^\circ=\left(\partial A\right)^\circ=\varnothing$.

Conversely, if $\left(\partial A\right)^\circ=\varnothing$ then $\partial\partial A=\partial A$.

Answer (score 0):

The circle is a counterexample, as in fact if $S^1$ is the circle $\partial(S^1) = S^1$.

Comment: So could one characterize the family of such sets as those for which they themselves are the boundary of another set?

Comment: No, we cannot. Consider $\mathbb{Q}^2 = A$. Then $\partial(A) = \mathbb{R}^2$, but $\partial(\mathbb{R}^2) = \emptyset$.A less helpful observation is that they are sets of the form $A = \partial\partial S$ (if you can't think of one, just set $A = S$. Bryan gives a better characterization.